# SSMS upgrade from 2008 R2 to 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql

I currently have a load-balanced cluster of servers running SQL Server 2008 R2 with the respective version of SSMS. I need to upgrade just the SSMS tool in order to export a BACPAC correctly. Are there any procedures or compatibility issues I should be aware of before upgrading just this component?

I have had a search for this already and from what I can see there aren't but I'm fairly new to this so may be missing something obvious...

It's in a Live environment so am sure you can appreciate the cautious approach....

Cheers

Comment: MyNizzle... Explain if this "live" environment you refer to has any installed instances of SQL Server on it which you are asking about upgrading the SQL Server components (not the SQL instance) i.e. SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)? You could technically put SQL Server SSMS 2016 components on any other machine that's not a "live" system and just connect to the SQL Server instance remotely from there to perform the BACPAC export, correct? **Best Practice Procedure**: `Make a complete full system backup (e.g. full system OS image) and a full file backup and then make the change (revert plan)`

Comment: Haha. Yes, the environment has 2008 R2 instances present, however, have already made the decision to install this on a separate utilities server as realize that best practice is to run tools from another server rather than use up valuable resources on the Live servers. I was aware this could be done by the way but firewall rules were limiting access to shared drives directly from my laptop and so required this to be installed on the actual SQL servers but think I've managed to work around this now.

This is a new environment that I've taken over so am weary of making changes this early.